# Did the Apple Newton employ machine learning for handwriting recognition?

Tags: newton

We know that the [Apple Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Newton) and the [Messagepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MessagePad) would recognize handwriting on the digital screen with the stylus based on the user training it to their style.

My question is: **Did the Apple Newton employ machine learning for handwriting recognition?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a paper "Combining Neural Networks and Context-Driven Search for On-Line, Printed Handwriting Recognition
in the Newton" stating that it was done using Artificial Neural Networks so it was a machine learning technique.

PDF: [shinyverse.org/larryy/Yaegeretal.AIMag.pdf](http://shinyverse.org/larryy/Yaegeretal.AIMag.pdf)

Website with additional info: [shinyverse.org/larryy/ANHR.html](http://shinyverse.org/larryy/ANHR.html)